# UIDate Picker can not changing width?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

In  my App.

I am using XCode 4.2.

And ios 4.3 BAse SDK.

I have UIDatePicker.

It's mode is Time.

So, I am changing its width from interfce builder.

In interface builder it look's desired,but in Simulator it's looks like spreaded border and kind of full size.

EDIT : Also I am changing the frame without changing the height though things are same. Anybody have some solution please suggest me.

Screens.
1) Interface builder
[image]

2)Simulator

[image]

Comment: Setting the width in Interface Builder should be working.  If it is not, [please file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) and it *will* be fixed.

Comment: How do you add your UIPicker? Only through Interface Builder or you add some code for it aswell? Seems like it's parameters get overriden as the picker on the 2nd image seems to have the default size and frame values.

Comment: I am doing nothing much programatically, just showing and hiding the pickerview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change values of x & y in the size inspector, also u need to specify the width of the date picker in the size inspector in the interface builder.
Hope this will help u out.